# Why does the instance of ModelStateDictionnary in my controller changes while processing a unique request?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-3.1

In .net Core 3 MVC, I have a controller with a constructor that instantiates a service class and passes the ModelState to the service:

```
public TransactionController(MyDbContextType dbContext):base(dbContext)
{

    _transactionDetailService = new TransactionDetailService(dbContext, this.ModelState);

}
```

Then in the same controller I have an action that uses the same instance of the service.
An error occurs while using that service, and - inside method DeactivateTransactionDetail - I add an error to the ModelState that was passed to the service:

```
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult DeleteTransactionDetail(int id)
            {
                [...]
    
                _transactionDetailService.DeactivateTransactionDetail(id);
    
                if(!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    HandleError();
                }
    
                [...]
            }
```

My problem is that HandleError is never executed because ModelState.IsValid is true.
But when I check the ModelState that I passed to _transactionDetailService, I find a different instance with ModelState.IsValid set to false - as expected.

These two instances of ModelStateDictionnary are different. I'm sure of this because I checked their hash codes.
I have also verified that my Controller instance is the same during all this process.

When and why does a new instance of ModeStateDictionnary get assigned to my Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ModelState` refers to a specific request's data. It's populated *after* the controller gets constructed, but before the action that handles the request is called. In the constructor, the `ModelState` has its default value.

If you want `DeactivateTransactionDetail` to have access to a request's state you should probably pass `ModelState` as a parameter to the method:

```
public TransactionController(MyDbContextType dbContext):base(dbContext)
{
    _transactionDetailService = new TransactionDetailService(dbContext);
}

...
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteTransactionDetail(int id) 
{
    ...
    _transactionDetailService.DeactivateTransactionDetail(ModelState,id);
    ...
}
```

To make testing easier, `TransactionDetailService` should be passed through a constructor parameter, not created inside the controller:

```
public TransactionController(MyDbContextType dbContext, 
                             TransactionDetailService svc):base(dbContext)
{
    _transactionDetailService = svc;
}
```

If you register this class with DI, the DI container will construct new instances of `MyDbContextType` and `TransactionDetailService` and pass them to the controller upon construction. Your controller constructor won't have to change at all :

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContextType>(options=>{...});   
services.AddScoped<TransactionDetailService>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This article is very misleading:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs

We tend to think that by using ModelState.IsValid we will get the error state that we set in the business layer/service layer, but in reality it will not.